# Blocking password based logins with usermod, allowing public key logins

Tags: linux, ssh

The manpage for usermod says this about locking a users account:

```
   -L, --lock
       Lock a user's password. This puts a ´!´ in front of the encrypted password, effectively disabling the password. You canÂ´t use this option with -p or -U.
```

I have tried to use this to have a user only log in with the public key, but when I lock the account I get a password prompt.
When I unlock the account again the public key works.

Edited: to make it clear: I want to be able to log in using the key still, and somehow locking the user gives me a password prompt when trying to use the key

Answer (score 3):

As the man page says, this *effectively* locks the password - as in, it makes it impossible to use the *existing* password on this account.

It does not disable password-based login - you need to set the correct sshd(8) options for that.

I assume you mean "remotely login via ssh", since I don't know how a public key would be used locally.

Comment: Ok..the password thing makes sense, but I can't explain how that would block my key-based access, and you're right, it's a remote login. I don't want to block ssh password logins, I do however want to have this keybased login continue to work if I block the password login for the user using usermod, and the weird thing is I found a whole lot of pages explaining that this is how to do that..

Answer (score 0):

Locking you password with `usermod` actually locks your whole account as you noticed. (System sees the `!` added in front of the password as sign to *not* allow you log in.)

If you break you password hash by putting e.g. `*` in front of it you can still log in with public key.

Really you want to have a password for possible console logins etc. but disable password logins from ssh.

/etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
  PasswordAuthentication no
```

Comment: Well I want to be able to have ssh passwords still, so I am probably going with your breaking the password hash trick. Does that break it to a degree that it's not brute force hackable either, or am I asking too much there..